# Flask: Hidden values from one page to another

Tags: flask, hidden-field, flask-wtforms

I've read the other questions but still can't figure out what's wrong.
I want to pass a hidden value from one page: dashboard to another: seegoodsrec
Hopefully someone can help.
I am using this form to obtain a hidden value:

```
class customerIDForm(Form):
    customerID = HiddenField()
```

This is then used in my dashboard:

```
@app.route('/dashboard/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    form = customerIDForm()
    customerID = form.customerID.data 
    return render_template("dashboard.html",form = form)
```

I feel up to here it's fine. But I can't figure out the html code. Inside a table I want the button to do the submit to my page seegoodsrec:

```
{% for t in TOPIC_DICT["goodsrec"] %}
<td>
<form method=post action="/seegoodsrec/">
<input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="{{j[0]}}"
    <a href="{{t[3]}}"><button type="submit" value=Save class="btn btn-primary"style=
" margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; height:44px; margin-right: 15px">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> {{t[2]}}</button></a>
</form>
</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Value `j[0]` is a variable, depending on the row inside the table you click, the button should submit the value to page `seegoodsrec`. This is how `seegoodsrec` is set up:

```
@app.route('/seegoodsrec/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def seegoodsrec():
    form = customerIDForm()
    customerID = request.form.get('customerID')
    return render_template("seegoodsrec.html",form = form)
```

The page `seegoodsrec` does not display the value customerID which come from `j[0]`. Any input is very much appreciated, thanks! I was simply trying on seegoodsrec:

```
<p>test{{customerID}}</p>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, to be such a pain, but I just can't figure out the correct way to do it. Maybe a screenshots from my page helps:
[Screenshot from my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RzGw.png)

So basically, what I need to do: When I click `View Details` I only want to see the details for customer in the row I clicked (depending on the ID). View details is going to take me to a new page called `seegoodsrec`. So, my idea was to pass a hidden values to page `seegoodsrec` which is the customer ID. This value I could then use to only display good receivers for that customer.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Wait, have you heard of sessions and cookies?

Comment: Yes, I have.. in fact I'm using them.. but not quite sure if I can do that just between two pages.. my understanding is that session refers to the global user session but the customerID I want to figure out can change between both pages, depending on where I click in the table..

Comment: @MarkWellings Can you perhaps describe your use case for this, that way it would be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: The FlaskApp is supposed to handle invoices for suppliers. As a supplier I have to create my customers and every customer can have various goods receiving parties. There is an overview of my customers and a button to see their respective goods receivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that helps anyone. Here is how I do my selection:

```
<form method=post action="/seegoodsrec/">                    
<a href="{{t[3]}}"><button type="submit" name="customerID"
value="{{j[0]|int}}" class="btn btn-primary" style=" margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px; height:44px; margin-right: 15px">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> {{t[2]}}
</button>
</a>
</form>
```

In flask:

```
def seegoodsrec():
customerID = request.form.get('customerID')
mySQL3 = SelectGoodsrec(session['ID']) #displayed goodsreceiver with user ID
mySQL8 = SelectGoodsrecSEE(customerID)
c, conn = connection()

x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM goodsrec WHERE Gr_Cm_id = (%s)",
                      [str(customerID)])
if int(x) < 1:
    flash("Please, create a goods receiver for this customer")
```

mySQL8 picks up the customerID and selects the respective goods receivers.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong here.

```
@app.route('/dashboard/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    form = customerIDForm()
    customerID = form.customerID.data
    ^ ~~~~~~~~
     This doesn't do anything. Consider doing it reverse?
    return render_template("dashboard.html",form = form)
```

Also, GET and POST are different. Please limit them to one, or write separate handlers.

Comment: form.customerID.data = customerID give me an error.

Comment: Every customer has got an ID which is assigned when inserting in the DB. With the input hidden in html I'm trying to pass the variable in j[0] to my page seegoodsrec. From there I only want to show the goods receivers with the ID obtained from the dashboard html ( third code in my post).

Comment: You should pass customerID to the template engine, if you want to render it in any way. You also seems to be using WTForms wrong, please read the tutorial again for the correct way.

Comment: Could you maybe give an example of how to pass an hiddenvalue from one page to another? I guess that would help a lot.